# Detect Safari 7 Smart Search Bar preloading in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, safari

We are developing a small site in NodeJS and have some problems with preloading of pages/routes. When the user (or developer) starts typing localhost in the address field in Safari 7, the browser preloads previously visited URLs from the local node server. This produces all kinds of weird behavior and it is not something that I earlier have had to deal with.

What are the preferred ways of dealing with this? Can it be solved using cache control headers? Or are there anything in the call from the browser that we can detect and filter those calls?